# How to draw multiple lines(Grid) in UITableView Cell?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, draw

I want to add multiple columns in UITableView. I have created one CustomeTableCell with two lines used `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method. But, i able to draw only 2 lines (3 columns). I have to draw multiple lines (Vertically),Eg: 5 - 10 columns. How can draw multiple lines in tableviewcell. Can you please suggest me any idea/sample code to complete this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making the backgroundColor black. Adding x white subviews to the contentView of the cell, with a 1px margin between them?

This would create the desired column look, and also add the benefit of being able to acces the columns easily, if the views were set as properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I took a UIView and set one image of 4X2 as its background and set the frame of uiview as `CGRectMake(0, 40, 330, 2)`. and then added the UIview in cell

```
[cell addSubview:uiviewwithImage];
```

Hope this method helps you. Thanks.
  [image: Check the Image]

Comment: I don't know if you are able to see,but I have posted my image next to thanks. you can take help of cmd+ for the same.

Comment: No image is visible. Also, using a static image is not the best solution. If you would want to support multiple screen resolution, you'd already need multiple images..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of actually drawing on the tableView try layer.border properties on the subviews of the cell.
This solves the issue if the subview edge & the grid line you want to draw have same X or Y coordinate.

If you want a margin between the subview & the grid line this may not work.